# how to keep moving my circular progress bar after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

```
import { Observer } from "mobx-react";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Platform,
  Dimensions,
  Clipboard,
} from "react-native";
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";
import AppStore from "../../stores/AppStore";
import Iconpack from "../../utils/Iconpack";
import Theme from "../../utils/Theme";
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";
import CircularProgressBar from "./CircularProgressBar";
import { Shadow } from "react-native-shadow-2";
import Toast from "react-native-simple-toast";
import { BoxShadow } from "react-native-shadow";
import FastImage from "react-native-fast-image";
// import Clipboard from "@react-native-community/clipboard";
const hRem = AppStore.screenHeight / 812;
const wRem = AppStore.screenWidth / 375;

export class OtpDetails extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
      indeterminate: true,
      clipboardText: "",
      textInputText: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animate();
  }

  animate() {
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({ progress });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ indeterminate: false });
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        progress += Math.random() / 30;
        if (progress > 1) {
          progress = 1;
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        this.setState({ progress });
      }, 600);
    }, 600);
  }
  render() {
    const shadowOpt = {
      width: 160,
      height: 170,
      color: "#fff",
      border: 2,
      radius: 70,
      opacity: 6,
      x: 0,
      y: 3,
    };
    const { myTitle } = this.props.route.params;
    const setTextIntoClipboard = async () => {
      await Clipboard.setString(myTitle);
      Toast.show("OTP copied successfully!", 200);
    };
    const deviceName = DeviceInfo.getModel();
    return (
      <Observer>
        {() => (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <FastImage
              style={styles.container}
              source={Iconpack.GLOBAL_BG}
              resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
            />
            <View style={styles.headerStyle}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  this.props.navigation.navigate("OtpScreen");
                }}
              >
                <Image
                  style={styles.backButton}
                  source={Iconpack.GLOBAL_BACK_BUTTON}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>{myTitle}</Text>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Image
                    style={[styles.editTrashButton, { marginRight: 19 }]}
                    source={Iconpack.EDIT_ICON}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.editTrashButton}
                    source={Iconpack.DELETE_ICON}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.circleOuter}>
              {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
                <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                  <Progress.Circle
                    style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
                    progress={this.state.progress}
                    indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
                    size={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.561}
                    thickness={10}
                    borderWidth={0}
                    endAngle={10}
                    strokeCap="round"
                    color={"#354659"}
                    indeterminateAnimationDuration={2000}
                    unfilledColor={"#031830"}
                  />
                </View>
              ) : (
                <Shadow
                  distance={20}
                  startColor={"rgba(27, 100, 206, 0.5)"}
                  radius={210}
                  safeRender={true}
                >
                  <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                    <Progress.Circle
                      style={{ alignItems: "center", overflow: "hidden" }}
                      progress={this.state.progress}
                      indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
                      size={Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.561}
                      thickness={10}
                      borderWidth={0}
                      endAngle={10}
                      strokeCap="round"
                      color={"#354659"}
                      indeterminateAnimationDuration={2000}
                      unfilledColor={"#031830"}
                    />
                  </View>
                </Shadow>
              )}

              <Text style={[styles.circleItem]}>{myTitle}</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setTextIntoClipboard();
                }}
                style={styles.copyItem}
              >
                <Text style={styles.copyText}>TAP TO COPY</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

            {/* <View style={styles.circleOuter}>
              <View style={styles.circleContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.circleItem}>title</Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  copyToClipboard();
                }}
                style={styles.copyItem}
              >
                <Text style={styles.copyText}>TAP TO COPY</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity> */}
            {/* </View> */}
          </View>
        )}
      </Observer>
    );
  }
}
export default OtpDetails;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#021831",
  },
  headerStyle: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: hRem * 56,
    marginHorizontal: wRem * 26.66,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  backButton: {
    width: wRem * 12,
    height: hRem * 21,
  },
  editTrashButton: {
    width: wRem * 23,
    height: hRem * 23,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed2,
    lineHeight: hRem * 16,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontWeight: "600",
    marginLeft: wRem * 50,
  },
  circleOuter: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  circleContainer: {
    borderRadius:
      Math.round(
        Dimensions.get("window").width + Dimensions.get("window").height
      ) / 2,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.56,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.56,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
    shadowColor: "rgba(27, 100, 206, 0.5)",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 30,
    shadowRadius: 30,
  },
  circleItem: {
    color: "white",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed7,
    textAlign: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    paddingBottom: 100,
  },
  copyItem: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: hRem * 64,
  },
  copyText: {
    color: "#3D4756",
    ...Theme.encodeSansMed4,
  },
});
```

I have added circular progress by using the react-native-progress library. I have implemented logic for moving bar for 30 sec but the thing is after 30 sec it stops, so I need to keep moving after 30 sec here my whole code.

Here is the logical part which I have added here...

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      progress: 0,
      indeterminate: true,
      clipboardText: "",
      textInputText: "",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animate();
  }

  animate() {
    let progress = 0;
    this.setState({ progress });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ indeterminate: false });
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        progress += Math.random() / 30;
        if (progress > 1) {
          progress = 1;
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
        this.setState({ progress });
      }, 600);
    }, 600);
  }
```

I have tried several ways but nothing is happening also function will be welcome for this question. thanks in advance

Comment: do you mean like you want the progress circle to continue loading INDETERMINATELY after the progress is done (30sec)?

Comment: **yes** @AmmarOker

Comment: you can just set `indeterminate` back to `true` after the progress reaches 1.

Comment: in here  this.setState({ indeterminate: true }); i have set to true but nothing ,it not moving although @AmmarOker

Comment: @AmmarOker any suggestions?